# Directory not showing up in desktop, and file not being created?

Tags: java, file, exception

The following program has the purpose of creating a directory,

```
     folderforallofmyjavafiles.mkdir();
```

and making a file to go inside that directory,

```
File myfile = new File("C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\folderforallofmyjavafiles\\test.txt");
```

There are two problems though. One is that it says the directory is being created at the desktop, but when checking for the directory, it is not there. Also, when creating the file, I get the exception

```
ERROR: java.io.FileNotFoundException: folderforallofmyjavafiles\test.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Please help me resolve these issues, here is the full code:

```
package mypackage;

import java.io.*;

public class Createwriteaddopenread {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    File folderforallofmyjavafiles = new File("C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop");

    try {
        folderforallofmyjavafiles.mkdir(); //Creates a directory (mkdirs makes a directory)

        if (folderforallofmyjavafiles.isDirectory() == true) {
            System.out.println("Folder created at " + "'" + folderforallofmyjavafiles.getPath() + "'");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Not working...?");
    }

    File myfile = new File("C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\folderforallofmyjavafiles\\test.txt");
    //I even tried this:

    //File myfile = new File("folderforallofmyjavafiles/test.txt");
    //write your name and age through the file
    try {
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(myfile); //Going to write to myfile
        //This may throw an exception, so I always need a try catch when writing to a file
        output.println("myname");
        output.println("myage");
        output.close();
        System.out.println("File created");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.printf("ERROR: %s\n", e); //e is the IOException
    }

}
}
```

Thank you so much for helping me out, I really appreciate it. 
:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating the `Desktop` folder in the `C:\Users\username` folder. If you check the return value of `mkdir`, you'd notice it's `false` because the folder already exists.

How would the system know that you want a folder named `folderforallofmyjavafiles` unless you tell it so?

So, you didn't create the folder, and then you try to create a file in the (nonexistent) folder, and Java tells you the folder doesn't exist.

Agreed that it's a bit obscure, using a `FileNotFoundException`, but the text does say "The system cannot find the **path** specified".

---

**Update**

You're probably confused about the variable name, so let me say this. The following are all the same:

```
File folderforallofmyjavafiles = new File("C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop");
folderforallofmyjavafiles.mkdir();

File x = new File("C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop");
x.mkdir();

File folderToCreate = new File("C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop");
folderToCreate.mkdir();

File gobbledygook = new File("C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop");
gobbledygook.mkdir();

new File("C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop").mkdir();
```

Comment: Then how do I specify the direct path to the desktop? And also, doing .mkdir() makes it into a folder right? Thank you so much for your answer, I really appreciate it.

Comment: You *did* give the direct path to the desktop, and `mkdir` *will* create the named folder if it doesn't already exist. Since `Desktop` already exists inside `C:\Users\username`, nothing was needed to be done.

Comment: Oh, alright. I figured out my problem. By doing \\desktop as the last part of the path, it was creating a folder "named" desktop. Since desktop already exists there, I needed to add another \\ and put the real name that I wanted, folderforallofmyjavafiles. I was trying to create a folder **named** folderforallofmyjavafiles, but instead I was unintentionally creating a folder named desktop, which already existed. Really that was the name of the **object** of the file class, right? Thank you so much for clarifying this concept. I have marked your answer as best answer and liked.